# Handle chained promise errors in async/await

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript

The code below is supposed to save various files into the db but in an event where one fails,  others still save but an error is returned. How do I tackle this situation to show an error message based on if none of the data was saved or one data from the list was not saved?

```
 try{
   await Promise.all([
      data1.save(), 
      data2.save(),
      .....
   ])
 }
 catch(ex){
   success: false,
   error: ex
 }
```

Comment: Don't call `save()` is really the "best" course of action here. MongoDB has `bulkWrite()` which allows "multiple" operations in a **single** request, thus obviating the need to trap promise responses and you can trap the errors within a batch. Unless for some reason the data is in different collections, which would require separate calls, but then again you're probably doing something wrong in the architecture if that is the case. You would get a more informative response by presenting what you are really trying to do. Presuming "promises are the answer" is likely not the "best" solution here

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn for the helpful explanation but they are in different collections that's why I used save()

Comment: I believe the point I was making about "different collections" is that you probably should not be doing that either. The best advice I can give is to "seek some advice" over your present design. Calling `save()` as a method is not great anywhere. So you probably could ask some smaller questions and gain some insight into what to do better. Chaining promises is a "sledgehammer" in a place where you really need more finesse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the errors on the individual `save()` functions and just return them or some value to indicate the error. Then the `Promise.all()` will collect both errors and results together for you deal with later:

```js
function save(n){
    // rejects on 'bad' input
    return n == "bad" ? Promise.reject("error") : Promise.resolve("worked")
}
async function saveThings() {
    try{
        let res = await Promise.all([
            save('good').catch((err) => err), 
            save('bad').catch((err) => err),
            save('good').catch((err) => err),
        ])
        return res

    } catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    } 
}
saveThings()
.then(console.log)
```